# FTPS connection error: gnutls_handshake failed

Tags: c, ssl, curl, libcurl, ubuntu-16.04

I researched about this question and could not find any pointers to this error. I am essentially trying to connect to server using libcurl program.

https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/ftpsget.html

The program compiles fine but gives a run time error as follows:

```
Trying (Some IP)...

* Connected to (Some server name) (same ip as above) port 21 (#0)
* found 173 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 697 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
* Closing connection 0
curl told us 35
```

I am having access to this server through a username& password.

Comment: sounds like gnutls couldn't complete the TLS handshake with the server...

Answer (score 0):

Kinda old question, but incase it helps others...

You might need to use --insecure --ftp-ssl --tlsv1 and maybe ftps:// but sometimes ftp://

Hope it helps!

EDIT:
URL attached
[FTPS connection error: gnutls_handshake failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38488122/ftps-connection-error-gnutls-handshake-failed)

Comment: By "old question", did you mean  someone has asked this on SO? If so, please attach the URL.